# Can 2 CSS classes activate the same script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

the script below makes the page fade out upon clicks on links that have class="nav".

I would like to have the script ALSO activated in the same way for links that have class="home".

How would would do this? Is there such a thing as $('.nav & .home')??

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.nav').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $('.mask').fadeIn('medium', function(){
            document.location.href = url;
        })
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use commas to specify [multiple selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/multiple#selector1selector2selectorN):

```
$('.nav, .home').doSomethingToBoth();
```

A lesser known alternative is to use [`add`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/add):

```
$('.nav').doSomethingToNavs().add('.home').doSomethingToBoth();
```

I should also add that doing `.class` selectors are slow. If you know that only `<a>` elements are going to have the `.nav` and `.home` classes, you should write your selector like this:

```
$('a.nav, a.home').click(...);
```

Without this jQuery will be forced to look at *every single element* in the document to see if it has the class you specified, as opposed to only looking for `<a>` elements with the native `getElementsByTagName` and THEN looking to see if they have the class specified. This is just a good practice to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

$('.nav, .home')...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav, .home")
```